# How to mark related entities as dirty in search api module when edited?

Tags: 7, entities, rules, search

I am using Drupal 7 with the search api. I understand that one of the 'common pitfalls' of the search api is 'Changes in related entities don't lead to re-indexing'. I am bringing in a field called 'Collection Reference' in my search api index as 'type = content' . So when the title of a collection changes the search API doesn't realise it has changed.
I have tried to sort this using the rules module as discussed - https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/modules/search-api/getting-started/common-pitfalls#indirect-changes - but I have not been able to get it working. Has anybody had any luck with this technique? Or another programmatical approach?